# Why can't I use the instance of PreferenceFragment() instead of the instance of Fragment()?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have read the artical https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/preference/PreferenceFragment

I think that PreferenceFragment is child class of Fragment

So I think I can always use PreferenceFragment() instead of Fragment().

But in Code A, I get error when I try to use `return MyPreferenceFragment()` instead of  return `PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)`, why?

**Code A**

```
class UITab : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mSectionsPagerAdapter: SectionsPagerAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_tab)

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        container.adapter = mSectionsPagerAdapter

        container.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs))
        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(container))
    }


    inner class SectionsPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            //return MyPreferenceFragment()   //It will cause error
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return 2
        }
    }



    class PlaceholderFragment : Fragment() {

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                                  savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, container, false)
            rootView.section_label.text =arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)?.toString()

            return rootView
        }

        companion object {
            private val ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number"
            fun newInstance(sectionNumber: Int): PlaceholderFragment {
                val fragment = PlaceholderFragment()
                val args = Bundle()
                args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber)
                fragment.arguments = args
                return fragment
            }
        }
    }


    class MyPreferenceFragment : PreferenceFragment() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.mypreference)
        }
    }

}
```

**To Mike M**
Thanks! The following code is my import

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import android.os.Bundle
import android.preference.*
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import info.dodata.mirror.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_fragment.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_tab.*
```

Comment: Check your imports. You're likely mixing support and platform `Fragment`s.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please see my modified question?

Comment: Yeah, `PreferenceFragment` is coming from `import android.preference.*`. I think you actually need [`android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat), since I don't believe there is a support class named `PreferenceFragment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FragmentPagerAdapter` is part of the Support Libraries and thus uses the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. The `PreferenceFragment` is a framework fragment which inherits from `android.app.Fragment`.

Instead of `PreferenceFragment` you should use the [`PreferenceFragmentCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat) compatibility class for your implementations.